# Broadcom wireless Driver on hp 15-ac098TU notebook not working properly

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have brought hp 15-ac098TU notebook Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
The wifi is not working properly. It gets connected to the wifi but connection keeps on dropping and it is very slow.

The details of the wireless device:

**Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)**

Wireless driver is : bcmwl-kernel-source-6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1

Please help me to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has it's problems with Broadcom drivers, I myself have a Lenovo laptop with the same wireless adapter and always have to manually install the drivers on any Linux distribution.

On Ubuntu the easiest way is to install the proprietary driver since the kernel integrated opensource drivers do not work with this card.
Firstly you have to get internet access on the device in any other way, be it through an ethernet cable or for example an android device. You can connect your phone to your WiFi and usb tether the connection to your laptop.

Next open the **Additional drivers** program from the Dash app launcher and look for the **Broadcom wireless adapter** (I am currently not on my ubuntu machine so I cannot check the exact text that will be shown, if anybody has the same card, free to comment and I'll edit the answer). Check the use proprietary driver checkbox and hit apply. It will take a few minutes and your driver will be installed. You might have to reboot to get apply the changes

Comment: As suggested, I have installed the proprietary driver but still the connection keeps on dropping. And it gets stuck while using the wifi connection. When I ping the wifi router the response time keeps fluctuating between 400 ms to  1 ms. Ideally it should be in 0 ms. I am with in the wifi range but still getting this strange behaviour.